# Date Format issue in swimlane charts in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to compare date type against string type and plot the same in chart using swimlane line chart in Angular 6. The problem is if i plot date field in x-axis it works fine. But if i plot it in y-axis it's not working as expected. It displays like 1,520,000,000,00..

I had tried with YAxisTickFormatting also and its too not producing the expected result. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drzddd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Html:

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart [animations]="false" [scheme]="lineChartColor" [results]="lineChartData" [xAxis]="true" [yAxis]="true"
      [showXAxisLabel]="true" [xAxisLabel]="'Name'" [showYAxisLabel]="true" [yAxisLabel]="'Date'" [roundDomains]="true" [yAxisTickFormatting]="dateTickFormatting" 
      [autoScale]="true"></ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

typescript:

```
    dateTickFormatting(val: any): String {
    if (val instanceof Date) {
      var options = { month: 'long' };
      return (<Date>val).toLocaleString();
    }
  }
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you create stackblitz to reproduce the issue?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drzddd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts